# Adding set of variables to different fields in pivot table using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am VBA novice trying to add certain variables to the values field (but this question can be expanded to other pivot table fields, like rows or columns fields).

I have weeks of the year that I would like to add all at once using VBA rather than one-by-one by hand (dragging and pulling).

I found the following code online that adds all variables to the values field, but I would like to edit it to be able to copy in a list of variable names to add rather than it add all of them.

```
Sub AddAllFieldsValues()
' Adds all fields to Values
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim I As Long
    For Each pt In ActiveSheet.PivotTables
        For I = 1 To pt.PivotFields.Count
            With pt.PivotFields(I)
              If .Orientation = 0 Then .Orientation = xlDataField
            End With
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Can anyone provide any edits to the above code to answer my question? If it needs further explaining please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: Where you say you have "weeks of the year" that you don't want to drag across, this implies that each of your weeks is a separate column. It might be easier to flatten your source table (if possible) and add a "week number" column. This will then trivialise your question, since you can just drag the "week number" field across.

Answer (score 0):

What Jonathan is referring to in his comment is commonly called 'Unpivoting'. Google "Unpivot", and you'll find a whole bunch of VBA code that does it for you, including an article I wrote at http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2013/11/21/unpivot-shootout/

(If you elect to use the code from that post, scroll down till you see the words "Update 26 November 2013". My code is very complicated, but handles the very rare end-case where the unpivoted dataset is too long to fit on the sheet).